# Keep object on top of deformed surface

Tags: armature

[image]

So this checkerboard has a simple deform modifier enabled and I'm wanting the knights feet to stick to the surface of the board. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to place it there? Or during an animation sequence? To jut place the knight use "Snap to Face Project" with "Align Rotation to Target"

Comment: Ah that's great thank you but i was thinking for an animation so it stays on whilst the plane twists

Comment: Then I think you want a "Child Of" constraint on the Knight. Make a vertex group in the board that you want the Knight to track to and assign that group in the Child Of constraint